# What should return the resulting expression of DynamicMetaObject.BindGetMember to express that the member does not exist?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

I have this (simplified) class which has dynamic members exposed via a `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`:

```
public abstract class MyDynViewModel: ViewModelBase, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new MyDynViewModelDynamicMetaObject(parameter, this);
    }

    public object GetDynamicObject(string name)
    {
        return GetChild(name) ?? GetCommand(name);
    }
}
```

Here is my (simplified) `BindGetMember` method:

```
public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
{
    var self = Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);
    Expression expression;
    var propertyName = binder.Name;
    var args = new Expression[1];

    args[0] = Expression.Constant(propertyName);
    expression = Expression.Call(self, typeof(MyDynViewModel).GetMethod("GetDynamicObject", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), args);

    var getMember = new DynamicMetaObject(expression, BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
    return getMember;
}
```

Basically, `GetChild(string)` and `GetCommand(string)` return `null` if there is no child/command that matches the name.

What happens here is that if I bind a non-existent child/command name in a XAML, the binding will successfully resolve to a `null` value.

However, the behavior I would like to have is that the binding does not successfully resolve. The reason is that it would allow me to use `PriorityBinding`.

So far, I got two solutions:

- throw a RuntimeBinderException if there is no matching child/command name. This is what the `dynamic` object does when you try to access an invalid member. But I think it's a bit too heavy here.
- return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, which is enough to have a `PriorityBinding` work (as explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

However, none of these solution lead to the usual binding error message:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '****'
>   property not found on 'object' ''Object' (HashCode=13794971)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=****; DataItem='Object' (HashCode=13794971);
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text'
>   (type 'String')

So, any idea/advice on the best way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can tell, the closest you're going to get is this:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'EX' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'Test'). BindingExpression:Path=EX; DataItem='Test' (HashCode=11280399); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Property path is not valid. 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject+MetaDynamic' does not have a public property named 'Items'.`

Now, how is tricky question. I see you have quite complicated code, that's because you're creating everything from zero. Have you considered this:

```
public class TestViewModel : DynamicObject
{
   public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
   {
       result = null;
       return false; // if we didn't find member.

   }
}
```

instead?

If that does not suit your needs, first, you'll want to modify your `GetDynamicObject` signature, with an extra parameter "result".

you need to wrap the functionality in your `Expression`, the pseudo-code:

```
public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
{
    var self = Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);
    Expression expression;
    var propertyName = binder.Name;
    var args = new Expression[1];

    args[0] = Expression.Constant(propertyName);
    expression = Expression.Call(self, typeof(MyDynViewModel).GetMethod("GetDynamicObject", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance), args);

    expression = "if GetDynamicObject returned false, means we found nothing.
          then we should return binder.FallbackGetMember(this, e)";

    var getMember = new DynamicMetaObject(expression, BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
    return getMember;
}
```

You can check [PropertyPath.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/PropertyPath.cs,6e6acdbd2da0c257) DLR implementation, and track it:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
// 6. IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
// This supports the DLR's dynamic objects
if (accessor == null && 
    SystemCoreHelper.IsIDynamicMetaObjectProvider(item))
{
    accessor = SystemCoreHelper.NewDynamicPropertyAccessor(
                    item.GetType(), propertyName);
}
```

Comment: I can't inherit from `DynamicObject` because I'm already inheriting from a base class that I can't modify.

Comment: I managed to have it work, thanks! I was willing to do something similar to your answer but i was missing the `binder.FallbackGetMember` method to invoke when the path is invalid.